# Is ApplicationInitialization sufficient alone to replace PreLoadEnabled?

Tags: iis-8, application-pool, iis-8.5, recycle

IIS 8.0 onwards, There are two properties,

1. PreLoadEnabled which fakes a request to specified page to start web application.
2. ApplicationInitialization module, initializes and fakes request in case of app pool recycle or crash.

Now if I setup ApplicationInitialization, do I still have to use PreLoadEnabled? These two things sound confusing. I tried to read documentation for both things, but I am still confused that why do I need to use both.